# How to resolve nested input types on graphql mutation

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma

So I'm having issues trying to resolve a mutation that contains nested input types from another input type, correct me if I'm doing a wrong design with the models.

This is the mutation, I'm using Playground to check it out:

```
mutation{
  createOrganization(
    name: "Bitas"
    staff: [
      {
        firstName: "Albert"
        lastName: "Chavez"
        position: "Developer"
        contactInformation:[
            {
                email: "hola@mail.com"
                phone:"9187631"
                linkedin: "whatever"
            },
            {
                email: "hola2@mail.com"
                phone:"91876312"
                linkedin: "whatever2"
            }
          ]
        }
    ]
  ){
    name
    staff{
      firstName
      contactInformation{
        email
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This mutation is creating a relationship between Organization and Employee, which at the same time is creating a relationship between Employee and Contact Information... here are the schemas:

```
type Organization {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    staff: [Employee!]!
}

type Employee {
    id: ID!
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
    position: String!
    contactInformation: [ContactInfo!]!
    belongsToOrg: Organization
}

input employeeInput {
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
    position: String!
    contactInformation: [contactInfoInput!]!
    belongsToOrg: ID
}

type ContactInfo {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    phone: String!
    linkedin: String!
    belongsTo: Employee!
}

input contactInfoInput {
    email: String!
    phone: String!
    linkedin: String!
}
```

Correct me if I'm not creating the mutations correctly

```
type Mutation {
    createOrganization(name: String!, staff: [employeeInput!]): Organization!
    createEmployee(firstName: String!, lastName: String!, position:String!, contactInformation: [contactInfoInput!]!): Employee!
}
```

And here are the functions to create:

```
function createEmployee(parent, args, context, info) {
    return context.prisma.createEmployee({
        firstName: args.firstName,
        lastName: args.lastName,
        position: args.position,
        contactInformation: {
            create: args.contactInformation
        },
    })
}

function createOrganization(parent, args, context, info) {
    return context.prisma.createOrganization({
        name: args.name,
        staff: {
            create: args.staff
        }
    })
}

function staff(parent, args, context) {
    return context.prisma.organization({id: parent.id}).staff();
}

function contactInformation(parent, args, context) {
    return context.prisma.employee({id: parent.id}).contactInformation()
}

function belongsTo(parent, args, context) {
    return context.prisma.contactInfo({id: parent.id}).belongsTo()
}
```

So when I hit the mutation on Playground, it gives me the error:

**Reason: 'staff.create[0].contactInformation' Expected 'ContactInfoCreateManyWithoutEmployeeInput', found not an object.**

Could please somebody explain me what this means?? Am I not designing correctly the schema or relationships?? Or perhaps is because too many levels of nested inputs??
If I console.log the contactInformation field on the createOrganization function the value is undefined.

Note: *When creating a Employee, the nested mutation works fine.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in input passed to prisma binding function.

Let us start by looking at `createOrganization` mutation. This is how field definition for `createOrganization` mutation looks like - `createOrganization(name: String!, staff: [employeeInput!]): Organization!` where `staff` is relational field of type `employeeInput` which looks as below:

```
input employeeInput {
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
    position: String!
    contactInformation: [contactInfoInput!]!
    belongsToOrg: ID
}
```

Note that `ContactInformation` field here is array of `contactInfoInput` which looks like:

```
type ContactInfo {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    phone: String!
    linkedin: String!
    belongsTo: Employee!
}
```

If we look at schema generated by Prisma, you will notice that for each relation field, we have nested mutation fields - `create`, `connect`, `update`, `upsert` etc. and when we call prisma binding, we need to adhere to Prisma's schema.

Now, if we look at resolver,

```
function createOrganization(parent, args, context, info) {
    return context.prisma.createOrganization({
        name: args.name,
        staff: {
            create: args.staff
        }
    })
}
```

`args.staff` is correctly being passed as `create` input here but problem is in `contactInformation` array present in `args.staff`. Its value does not match with `ContactInfoCreateManyWithoutEmployeeInput` type defined in Prisma's schema. Changing above resolver to following will fix issue for you but I would suggest better designing input types for mutations:

```
function createOrganization(parent, args, context, info) {
    const { staff } = args
    return context.prisma.createOrganization({
        name: args.name,
        staff: {
            create: staff.map((emp) => ({
               firstName: emp.firstName,
               lastName: emp.lastName,
               position: emp.position,
               contactInformation: {
                   create: emp.contactInformation || []
               }
            }))
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Apparently this solution is not working... I got this error:

Reason: 'staff.create[0].firstName' Expected non-null value, found null.

Comment: So I suppose I need to iterate the staff array that is passed... and then iterate over the contact information array.. is this correct?? If so, why the employee mutation doesn't need to iterate??

Comment: I updated code to iterate through `staff` array, I missed that earlier. In case of `createEmployee` mutation, you have only one relational field in `contactInfo` called `belongsTo` which is not being passed in input I guess and that is the reason mutation is working as you already have `create` for contactInfo. Things will break when `belongsTo` is set in input.